# Create controller, model and view CAKEPHP 3

Tags: cakephp, model, controller, frameworks

I've just started to use cakephp but I have a lot of doubts.

First of all:

When I create a Controller, model and view with a DB conection with:

```
cake bake all "name"
```

it works fine but when I need no DB for one part of my webpage I can't do anything because it don't work.

So I delete this files:

```
/src/Controller/MyController.php
/src/Model/Entity/Model.php
/src/Model/Table/MyTable.php
/src/Template/MyTemplate/*
/tests/TestCase/*
```

And add the following line in routes.php

```
$routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'inicio']);
```

This works, but when I do this I can't see my layout in my page

I have the conection to Bootstrap and my header and footer in the layout but now I don't work, and now I don't have a controller to do my code in.

How can I do a controller model and view without a DB?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> And add the following line in routes.php
>
> `$routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display',
>   'inicio']);`
>
> This works, but when I do this I can't see my layout in my
>   page

Create empty inicio.ctp and don't use `$this->layout = false;`

> How can I do a controller model and view without a DB?

Bake new controller with command `cake bake controller Home`  or your controller name.

Inside generated controller use empty methods, without calling Models / ORM methods, or set some variables, like

```
public function index()
{
 // this is empty method
}

public function aboutUs()
{
 $about_us = [
   'title' => 'My title here',
   'description' => 'some text..'
 ];
 $this->set(compact('about_us'));
}

public function contact()
{
 // Add Modelless form here
}
```

Modelless Forms: **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/form.html**

Note: you can add these methods at PagesController and just route, for example:

```
$routes->connect('/contact', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'contact']);
```